# Disabling Touch-to-Click when TrackPad Appears as PS/2 Generic Mouse

Tags: mouse, trackpad, input-devices

I have a Vostro 3560 with Ubuntu 13.10.
I want to disable my touchpad's touch-to-click ability.

> gpointing-device-settings

shows my trackpad as a PS/2 Generic Mouse so it's not very helpful.